# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined while making async call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

I have been trying to work on application doing server side rendering. But I have been stuck where I am getting error 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'. As soon as my request goes to server for rendering the page, I need to load initial state from database and put it in store.But when I try to fetch data from server side I get the above error. Please find my server side code for rendering initial page

```
if (renderProps) {

  const components = renderProps.components;

  var componentObj = renderProps.components[2].WrappedComponent;
  const fetchData = (componentObj && componentObj.fetchDatas) || (() => Promise.resolve());
  const { location, params, history } = renderProps;
  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  // calling this function which is place inside another component
  // I get error at below line stating cannot read property .then of undefined
   fetchData({ store, location, params, history })
  .then(() => {
    const markup= renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
      </Provider>
    )

    const state = store.getState();
    return res.render('index', { markup,initialState: 
    JSON.stringify(store.getState()) });
    // if the current route matched we have renderProps
   }).catch((err)=> {
    console.log("error",err);
   })
  }
```

Please find my code where I defined the function which is getting called

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.getCoffeeOrders();
  }
  // call the action creator
  static fetchDatas({store}) {
     store.dispatch(getCoffeeOrders);
  }
  render() {
    // render code goes here
}
```

}

Also Please find my action creator which makes a async call in action creator to fetch the data from server

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_COFFEE_ORDERS = 'FETCH_COFFEE_ORDERS';
export  function getCoffeeOrders() {
//below line is getting printed on console
console.log("getting coffee orders inside");
return ((dispatch,getState) => {
    // below line is not getting printed
    // I think control does not come here 
    console.log("mKe a call");
     return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/fetchcoffeeData').then((response)=> {
        console.log("got response", response);
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_COFFEE_ORDERS,
            data
        });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("got error while fetching data",err);
    });
});
}
```

Control does not comes to the line which I printed in getCoffeeOrders inside another function. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't return the promise in fetchDatas static function it should be something like this:

```
static fetchDatas({store}) {
   return store.dispatch(getCoffeeOrders);
}
```

But I'm still not sure if redux dispatch returns anything take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/61)